# Send database data to a set html page

Tags: java, html, mysql, servlets

I'm building a dynamic web project using HTML, MYSql and Java Servlets and it is been run on tomcat server.

Have everything working so far as storing and extracting from the DB. I am displaying back to a HTML web page using

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println();
```

but this creates a new web page each time and this is not what i want. What i want is to have the data sent back to a webpage in my site..

My question is: Is there a way to get the Servlet to send it back a set web page??

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

You can set a value as a request attribute and forward the request. (Do not use `response.setContentType` when doing this, since the servlet will not be sending a response but forwarding to a JSP that will send the response.):

```
request.setAttribute("somevar", somevar);
request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
return;
```

Then in your JSP:

```
String somevar = (String)request.getAttribute("somevar");
out.print(somevar);
```

Or using JSTL and EL:

```
 <c:out value="${somevar}" />
```